# Default value for grunt.option?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

From cmd line I need to be able to set a flag and compile different files dependant on that flag. I believe you can achieve this with grunt.option.

```
grunt --env="dev"
```

But if this flag is omitted, I wish for their to be a default value in my grunt file.

```
grunt.option('env')
```

How can I set a default value for env if the user does not supply it as a flag when compiling?

Comment: Couldn't this work if you check for the `node.process.ENV` variable?

Comment: The answer is in the first example on the grunt.option documentation page: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper task, which will set grunt.option('env') to a default value if none was provided when the task was invoked:

```
function initBuild() {
    if (!grunt.option('env')) {
        grunt.option('env', 'your-default-value-here');
    }

    grunt.task.run(taskList);
}

grunt.registerTask('build', initBuild);
```